# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number, binding

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I am currently trying to bind variables into a SQL Query. I am using the Cx_Oracle Library.

```
c.execute("""
    select employee_id, first_name, last_name, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), salary from employees
    order by 1
    """)
```

This Query work perfectly fine and I get the desired output.

But if I try these two queries, I get the `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

I tried these methods to bind the variables:

```
tempo = "employees"
test_query = "select employee_id, first_name, last_name, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), salary from :temp"
    c.execute(test_query, temp=tempo)
```

--> Error I mentioned earlier

The second method:

```
c.execute("""
    select employee_id, first_name, last_name, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), salary from :table_name
    order by 1
    """, table_name="employees")
```

--> `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00903: Invalid Table Name`

I don't understand, why this binding isn't working, does anyone have a clue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It did. Thanks, I didn't found this question earlier.

Comment: The cx_Oracle manual on binding https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html also mentions that only data, not the text of the sql statement, can be bound.